# Why two info.plist files in an ipa file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ipa

When I extract and see my ipa file, I am able to see two info.plist files in ipa in the following path.

```
AppName.ipa\Payload\AppName.app\en.lproj\MainStoryboard.storyboardc\

AppName.ipa\Payload\AppName.app\
```

I have problems because of this in enterprise app distribution as the server parses the first plist file instead of second one. Because of that, in plist that server generates, bundle-identifier becomes empty. Could anyone please guide me whether the plist file found in the path `AppName.ipa\Payload\AppName.app\en.lproj\MainStoryboard.storyboardc\` is necessary and if not, how to remove/avoid this plist file when building the ipa file.

Comment: How do you know it's the extra info.plist file that's causing the BundleID to be blank?

Comment: because the extra info.plist does not have the BundleID and I am able to install the ipa file with single info.plist file.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's necessary or not... I've never heard of this. But, assuming it's not, you could create a post-build script in Xcode to simply 'rm YOUR_DIRECTORY\AppName.ipa\Payload\AppName.app\en.lproj\MainStoryboard.storyboardc\'